# Programmatically add UIImageViews to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For each cell in my tableView I want to programmatically add `UIImageViews` because each cell will have a different number of imageViews. When I insert a new cell, it contains the imageViews from the next cell. How do I make sure the imageViews do not overlap onto other cells?

This is the method I use in my custom `UITableViewCell` to add the imageViews.

```
 -(void)setImageViews:(int)images{
      x=0;
      for (int i=0;i<images;i++){
           UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,5, 36, 36)];
           [imgV setImage:[dic objectForKey:@"image"]];
           [self addSubview:imgV];

           x=x+36;
      }
 }
```

I thought I had to retain a unique identifier for each cell and check if it matches the current cell.  Something like this

```
-(void)setImageViews:(int)images forIndexPath:(int)row{
     if ((!self.cellIdentifier)||([self.cellIdentifier isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", row]])){
         self.cellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", row];
          x=0;
          for (int i=0;i<images;i++){
               UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,5, 36, 36)];
               [imgV setImage:[dic objectForKey:@"image"]];
               [self addSubview:imgV];

               x=x+36;
          }
     }
}
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a known max limit on the number of images a cell could contain?

Comment: @AdamPro13 I didn't add this above but if an imageView gets cut off at the edge of the screen I break the loop. So max images is however many fit until getting cut off.

Comment: You should be adding your image subviews to `self.contentView` not `UITableViewCell` directly

Answer (score 0):

Implement in Custom UITableViewCell

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    contentView.subviews.forEach { (subView) in
        if let imageView = subView as? UIImageView {
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```